# C# RestSharp uploading image to Laravel API

Tags: c#, laravel, xamarin.forms, restsharp

I have a Laravel API (PHP) and I want to upload an image from my Xamarin.Forms android app. I have this  code below:

```
public void UploadImage(string filePath) {
    var httpClient = Globals.g_HttpClient;
    var request = new RestRequest("upload_attachments");
    request.Method = Method.PUT;
    request.AddHeader("KEY", Globals.APIKey);
    request.AddFile("File", filePath);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    var response = httpClient.Put(request);
    var contentResponse = Convert.ToString(response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine(contentResponse);
}
```

I understand that the parameters for `request.AddFile()` is the `name` and `path-to-actual-file` respectively, but it seems that the attachments are not being sent. There are 0 files attached to my request, I view the actual request by using `dd($request)` in Laravel. This is the return for the `dd`:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#50
  ...
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#51
    #parameters: []
  }
  ...
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#55
    #parameters: []
  }
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#53
    #parameters: []
  }
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#56
    #headers: array:7 [
      "key" => array:1 [
        0 => "KcUup1OR8zRwI99BNRtapQJF8xPMsHj1"
      ]
      "accept" => array:1 [
        0 => "application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml"
      ]
      "user-agent" => array:1 [
        0 => "RestSharp/106.11.4.0"
      ]
      "content-type" => array:1 [
        0 => "multipart/form-data; boundary=-----------------------------28947758029299"
      ]
      "content-length" => array:1 [
        0 => "20426"
      ]
      "host" => array:1 [
        0 => "loan.phcci.coop"
      ]
      "accept-encoding" => array:1 [
        0 => "gzip, deflate"
      ]
    ]
    #cacheControl: []
  }
  ...
}
```

As you can see, `+files` returns an empty array. That is where the files should be if there are any included in the request.

Comment: what is the actual file path you are using?  Are you sure that it's valid and points to an actual file?

Comment: Try a `dd($_FILES)` -- this will conclude if issue is from Laravel or Android app

Comment: @Jason The actual android path to the image, example ```"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.loanapp2/files/Pictures/temp/images (3)_16.jpeg"```

Comment: @user8555937 The response code from ```dd($_FILES)``` is a blank array ```[]```

Comment: We write files to the request stream for sure. https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/fd23c08302ffe71d60c40bc683a05b694650dd3e/src/RestSharp/Http.cs#L288

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is actually because I'm using the `PUT` method when I should be using `POST`. I usually use `PUT` to create resources but it doesn't work when there are files attached.